# cannot do composer update 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

I'm still new to php laravel, so your help will really be appreciated

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.9
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.7.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.0
    - laravelcollective/html 5.4.x-dev requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4.1 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4.2 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4.3 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4.4 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4.5 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4.6 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4.7 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4.8 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4.9 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - don't install illuminate/view 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.7.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.7.x-dev, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.2, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - Installation request for laravelcollective/html 5.4.* -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[5.4.x-dev, v5.4, v5.4.1, v5.4.2, v5.4.3, v5.4.4, v5.4.5, v5.4.6, v5.4.7, v5.4.8, v5.4.9].
```

I'm actually trying to run my php file, but it shows

> Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found

So I searched through the internet and they said i need to update,  when i tried to update this happens, does anyone know what I need to do?

Also  I added to **config/app.php**

```
Inside Providers

Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
Inside aliases

'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Hope anyone can help

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: `laravelcollective/html v5.4 requires illuminate/view 5.4.*` -> does your env have illuminate/view 5.4.* or above?

Comment: Please share more information about the command you run and attach your composer.json. It looks like you want to remove a package?

Comment: using php 7.1.2 if not mistaken, but i'm sure it's above 7

Comment: i don't want to remove a package, i'm actually wan to run laravel form, but I can't do it because I have the error Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because your composer.json file has `laravelcollection/html` package with version `5.4` which is compatible with `Laravel 5.4` but you are using `Laravel 5.7`, I would advise you try and check your `composer.json` and update that line where you are adding that package to:

```
"laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0",
```

After doing this I would advise you do `composer update`, if it fails, then you will have to remove this package above, because it is not compatible with the latest `Laravel` version, or ofcourse you can decrease the `Laravel` version, whatever is okay with your application needs.

Also, every `illuminate/*` package is actually `Laravel core code`, those are base packages that laravel is made of.

Comment: so by decreasing my laravel version, will it effect my code, which means does some of the syntax I'm currently using will change? if i change to laravel 5.4

Comment: If you are using latest features from `Laravel 5.7` then yes, it will break your application, if you are not, it won't. You can check that [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade)